# Visual Studio / C# SQL command not executed

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am working with a SQL database and since this morning I do not get any result from queries in Visual Studio / C#: The code below `ExecuteNonQuery()` will just never be reached. Last Friday, everything worked fine. If I try to execute the same query with PhpStorm, it works.

**Has someone any idea, how to find out what the problem is?**

This is what my code looks like:

```
// Create the connection
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Con.Open();

// Delete every entry in the database table
SqlCommand DeleteCommand = Con.CreateCommand();

DeleteCommand.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName];"

DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

// code below is not reached
```

Changing the timeout is not helping.

I am using:

- Sql Server 2008 (running on its own server)
- Visual Studio 2013
- .NET v4.0.30319
- Windows 8.1

Thanks!

**Edits:**

- The table is currently empty, but filling it with a sample record does not help
- I tried to replace the statement with eg. `SELECT 1 FROM [TableName]`, did not work
- When I'm debugging and press F10 at `ExecuteNonQuery()`, I get the same behavior: just no reaction. No other code gets executed.
- Putting the query into a transaction does not help

Comment: What do you mean by _never be reached_? Your code goes to somewhere else? Did you debug your code and see what happens?

Comment: A breakpoint at any line below `ExecuteNonQuery()` will never be reached (or at least not for ~10 min)

Comment: btw: You can see where the execution of your program was, when you press the "pause" button

Comment: Did you check whether ConnectionString is correct, did you consider putting this into a transaction?

Comment: try to get some small data (with select query) just to check if the connection is ok

Comment: The connection string should be fine, credentials are the same as in PhpStorm.
@ Soner: No the programm seems to wait until it gets a result at the Execute statement

Comment: @Rafal: What do you mean by "putting this into a transaction"?

Comment: @LeifB `using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using(IDbTransaction transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(SpecifyIsolationLevel) 
    {
        SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        //add this text etc.
        //Execute command and commit transaction.
    }
}`

Comment: **EDIT** oh no, i was wrong, it did not...  (This seems to work! I will look a bit closer at this, thanks! )

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 con.Open();
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
 {
 cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName];"
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in the real code i am using `using` blocks ;) I just tried to shorten the code

Comment: @LeifB I understand you got this working, although don't try shorten your code. Just change the variable names etc. If this was a big problem (not one that required restart), how can we fix it? You could have potentially removed the fault code.

Answer (score 0):

So, actually restarting my computer did solve the problem, while restarting VS did not...

Sorry, but I did not expect this. Thanks for your help!